# Can you go back to the Blue Ribbon Restaurant?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I just bought the season pass and apparently I need to go to the Blue Ribbon Restaurant to pick up the rewards. I'm in Finkton, so I'm a fair ways into the game. Is there any way to go back quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think that you can. I pre-ordered the game and got the Industrial Revolution pack (and entered the code before I started playing). When I got to the Blue Ribbon Restaurant, the game told me to pick up my rewards before leaving, or else I wouldn't be able to get my rewards.

According to the [official FAQ](http://www.bioshockinfinite.com/news/bioshock-infinite-faq), if you redeem your season pass and you are past the Blue Ribbon Bar, your rewards will be placed into your inventory.